# How to track different units in Google Analytics

Tags: php, google-analytics, units-of-measurement

I'm just thinking what is the better way to track the following things in Google Analytics. So I decided to ask you first, before I regret it afterwards.

A seeds shop sells seeds by corn or by portion (10-30 corns).

In the Google Analytics `pageTracker._addItem` there is this variation param. But I'm not sure if it get's a mess later.

If you buy 1 portion:

```
pageTracker._addItem("orderId",  "productId",  "productName",  "perPortion",   "4.50",  "1");
```

If you buy 100 corns:

```
pageTracker._addItem("orderId",  "productId",  "productName",  "perCorn",   "40.00",  "100");
```

If I track it this way then I have an exact tracking of all orders. Or makes it more sense if I convert all orders to one unit (for example perPortion)?

I don't know if theres an easier way?

Comment: Isn't it way more reliable to match this kind of business logic with your own database, where you stored all orders and order items? If you want to meassure the interest in a product, I'd use pretty urls for each product and lookup which one gets most hits.

Comment: Use the smallest unit (perCorn), else you end up with fractions for quantity in your reports which looks awkward (although it' not a technical problem since the quantity parameter is a string). And you should really update your analytics code because that looks really out of date (i.e. switch to Universal Analytics as soon as your account shows that the transfer tool to UA is ready for your account).